# Supervisor don't see playback recording in freePBX UCP dashboard

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

My IT Head surely change the default location where call recordings are being saved, as a result Team Leads can no longer view playback button in UCP, they cannot do call listening.

I believe that UCP will get recording data from the default location.

Question: How do we change or tell UCP to get the recording from a new location that my IT Head define. see snip image, someone said I have to look for a file and edit it there.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMhQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have look in ucp folder, find fragment with default path(using grep or other util) and change it.

As other option you can do symlink to new dir.

Comment: tnx buddy..we'll check this one. as of the moment we're fixing a new issue since we cannot login using root account in freepbx via putty. we'll get back to this soon.